# Помогите с питоном

Tags: python, windows, процесс

Как сделать так, чтобы при открытии диспетчера задач, закрывался mspaint? (На питоне пожалуйста), заранее спасибо. Если вам будет интересно почему задаю такой вопрос, мне хочется узнать поподробней как это всё работает.

Comment: Советую ознакомиться: [Как задать хороший вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) и [Как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 4):

Для этого прекрасно подойдёт библиотека [psutil](https://github.com/giampaolo/psutil) (`pip install psutil`). Это универсальное и кроссплатформенное решение.

Вот пример использования:

```
import psutil # pip install psutil

for process in psutil.process_iter():
    if process.name() == "Taskmgr.exe":
        print("Task manager found!")
        break
else:
    print("Task manager not found!")
```

В этом коде перебирается список всех процессов и, если встречается процесс с именем `Taskmgr.exe` выполняется `print()` и завершение цикла. В случае если `break` не выполнился - вызывается код после `else` (если процесс `Taskmgr.exe` не найден)

А вот код, который решает вашу задачу:

```
import psutil
import time

taskmgrFound = False

while not taskmgrFound:
    for process in psutil.process_iter():
        if process.name() == "Taskmgr.exe":
            taskmgrFound = True
            print("Task manager found!")
            break
    else:
        print("Task manager not found. Trying again...")
        time.sleep(0.5)

msPaintPID = -1
for process in psutil.process_iter():
        if process.name() == "mspaint.exe":
            msPaintPID = process.pid
            break
else:
    print("Taskmanager was found, but mspaint is ofline!")

psutil.Process(msPaintPID).kill()
print("msPaint finished!")
```

Здесь работает цикл `while`, который выполняется до тех пор, пока не будет запущен *диспетчер задач*.

Далее идёт поиск `mspaint`. Когда тот найден - его *PID* (Process ID) сохраняется в переменную, а затем `mspaint` завершается по этому ID.

---

И последнее - как узнать что, например, диспетчер задач называется именно `Taskmgr.exe`, а не как-то иначе?

- Для Windows:

  1. Запускаем нужный процесс
  2. Ищем его в диспетчере задач
  3. Нажимаем на нём ПКМ -> свойства
  4. В строке правее от иконки файла будет его имя

[image: process name]

- Для Linux

  1. Запускаем нужный процесс
  2. Открываем терминал
  3. Пишем `ps -e`
  4. В колонке **CMD** ищем имя процесса

Надеюсь, помог вам `:)`